# How to add / replace values in a nested object (without losing original references) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, data-structures

I have to update a nested object with the new data without losing references in the original object. I think my problem is best explained with an example:

**Original Object:**

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": {
    "three": 3,
    "four": {
      "five": 5
    }
  }
}
```

**Update object:**

```
{
  "two": {
    "three": 5,
    "four": {
      "five": 7,
      "new": 8
    }
  }
}
```

**Final object:** (while retaining references in original object)

```
{
  "two": {
    "three": 5,
    "four": {
      "five": 7,
      "new": 8
    }
  }
}
```

So while it may look like the *Update* object and *Final* object are exactly the same, the thing to note is that I have to keep the references from the original object (i.e. I *don't replace* the "two" object or the "four" object inside the "two" object, only update their values).

The reason for preserving references is that because I'm using the data structure to create various bindings in AngularJS. I've tried using `angular.copy` but it does not give me the desired effect. Also if there is a pure JS implementation for this, I'd love to see it so that I can learn from the code.

**What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?**

Comment: is final object a new object?

Comment: hi,  no it is created by extending or modifying the `old` object

Comment: Why is the "one" property removed? from the original object?

Comment: If you want the "one" property to stay, you can use [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Comment: Are you saying that one of `Update` and `Final` object have references back to the original objects and the other does not?

Comment: Or are you saying that you want a _new_ object (not a reference to the original object) that contains references to the original sub-objects?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the `final` object has same key and values and `update` but the important part is that `obj.two` and `obj.two.four` are same references from the `original` object.

Comment: @MichaelL.I'm not sure we can create a new object but assign references from the `original` object? Regardless, my aim is to preserve the references from the original object, delete the keys which have no reference in the `update` object and overwrite `string` values that are both in the `original` object and `update` object

Comment: As far as I know, for Angular bindings, it doesn't matter if the "references" are the same; you can trash the original object and build a new one. As long as the path to the property remains the same so that on the next digest, it can $eval() the expression correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you. First the unwanted keys are deleted and then the values updated.

```js
function deep(o, u) {
    var keysO = Object.keys(o),
        keysU = Object.keys(u);

    keysO.forEach(function (k) {
        if (-1 === keysU.indexOf(k)) {
            delete o[k];
        }
    });
    keysU.forEach(function (k) {
        if (u[k] !== null && typeof u[k] === 'object') {
            if (o[k] === null || typeof o[k] !== 'object') {
                o[k] = {};
            }
            deep(o[k], u[k]);
            return;
        }
        o[k] = u[k];
    });
}

var original = { one: 1, two: { three: 3, four: { five: 5 } } },
    update = { two: { three: 5, four: { five: 7, "new": 8 } } };

deep(original, update);
console.log(original);
```

Comment: Awesome.. this is exactly what I was looking for.. just plugged this in my code and it is working fabulously.. Now I will try to understand this code, esp. the recursion part. Million thanks for it.

Comment: Perfect! Wrote almost the same :) http://plnkr.co/edit/pYpjLRj36KAlWO1oNB0U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Clone the object and then update the properties what you need.

Objects are passed by reference and hence it should be cloned.

**To clone:**

```
Object.assign(target, sources...);

var originalObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var updatedObj = {};
Object.assign(updatedObj, originalObj);
```

now you can update the updatedObj and the originalObj will be preserved.